# Optimize a rank query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query to fetch user's rank from Sql Server DB:

```
select user_rank
from (select t.user_id, rank() over (order by score desc) as user_rank
  from user_stats t
 ) t
where t.user_id='some_user_id';
```

The table consists approximately 22,000 rows and the query takes 3.5 seconds, which is too slow.

There are several indexes on this table, these are the relevant:

> user_id - Unique, NONCLUSTERED INDEX
>
> score - Non-unique, NONCLUSTERED INDEX

If I change the query and use id (which is my primary key) instead of user_id, then the query executes fast:

```
select user_rank
from (select t.id, rank() over (order by score desc) as user_rank
  from user_stats t
 ) t
where t.id='some_id';
```

After checking the Execution plan I see that Clustered index scan cost is 92%, though I don't really understand why it's needed in this case.

What can be done to optimize this query?

The statistics of the query:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:    CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 0 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected) Table 'users_stats'. Scan count 1, logical
> reads 22529, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
> 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 78 ms,  elapsed time = 3576
> ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
> time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Comment: You are going to have a scan here no matter what because your subquery has to look at every single row of the table. Not sure why it would 3.5 seconds but without the table and index definitions it is only guess work.

Comment: If UserID is unique then what is the purpose of ranking one user?

Comment: But why is there such a difference between using user_id and id as they both indexed?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - I'm using this query in a stored procedure which returns the ranking of a specific user.

Comment: @UdiI, is UserID unique in user_stats table? It will return you 1 row won't it?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - No, it will return the ranking of the user, that's the reason I use the subquery.

Comment: @UdiI, how can it be that it it will return more then one row? You say that it is unique and you are filtering by specific user. It should return 1 row

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - it does return 1 row, but the content of user_rank is the ranking of this specific user

Comment: @UdiI, can you show message tab when you execute your query with `SET STATISTICS IO ON`
`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`? Also add actual execution plan screenshot

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - added the statistics to the original question

Comment: Have you tried with 'PARTITION BY' with User_id in RANK()? Something like this,

select user_rank
from (select t.user_id, rank() over (partition by user_id order by score desc) as user_rank
  from user_stats t
 ) t
where t.user_id='some_user_id';

Comment: @UdiI, wow. 22529 this means that 22 thousand pages was read from cash. Are there really just 22000 rows? Do you have in your table large column like VARCHAR(MAX) BINARY IMAGE? Can you try to delete those columns. I can not reproduce your problem. I can get large logical reads when adding BINARY(8000) to table but I get 50 ms time

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the main reason for your performance degradation is because your index is not covering.  You would likely see a substantial improvement in performance by making the index covering.  [Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) is a good article that discusses covering indexes.

In a nutshell, the index offers simply a pointer to the row.  In order to get the data for the "score" column, which is needed to rank the result set, the engine must scan the clustered index in order to look-up the data.  If you include the value in the index, the engine will be able to perform the operation without needing the clustered index scan.

The index should be rewritten as follows:

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_USER_STATS_USER_ID ON user_stats (user_id) INCLUDE (score);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
select user_rank
from (select t.id, rank() over (order by score desc) as user_rank
  from user_stats t
 ) t
where t.id='some_id';
```

what about

```
with t as (
  select t.user_id, 
  ROW_NUMBER() as user_rank
  from user_stats t
  order by score desc
)
select user_rank
from t
where t.id='some_id';
```